# Objective c key path operators @avg,@max 

Tags: objective-c

```
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:45]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:23]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12]];
NSLog(@"The avg = %@", [arr valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.intValue"]);
```

This code works fine, but why? `valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.intValue"` is requesting (int) from each NSNumber, but we are outputting a %@ string in the log. If i try to output a decimal %d i get a number that possibly is a pointer to something. Can somebody explain why the integers become NSNumbers when i call the @avg operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueForKeyPath:` must return an object (its return type is `id`), so you get an NSNumber or NSValue (I'm not sure which; it depends on whether the `intValue` gives an int or NSNumber, and (if the former) how the result is bundled back into an object), despite the `intValue`. It's the same reason you can't store non-objects in collections.

Answer (score 1):

The `@avg` operator returns an `NSNumber` instance. If you use `%d`, you will print the memory address of the `NSNumber` instance. When you use `%@`, on the other hand, the `NSNumber` instance is sent a `description` message, and the resulting `NSString` is printed.

See [Set and Array Operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html) in the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html) for more information on `@avg` and other operators.